# positioning div using float

Tags: html, css

I have a figcaption that I want to position divs inside. I'm new to css and can't figure out how to do this. I know there's a float method but can't get my head around it. I've been at this for days now and am really stuck :( 
Here's the fiddle(I know it doesn't work but I don't have a way of linking the external css): http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/6uhw8c1p/

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
                <header>
                    <h1>Caption Hover Effects</h1>
                </header>

                <ul class="grid cs-style-2">

                    <li>
                           <figure>
                                <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">


          <figcaption>   

              <h3></h3>

                 <div>    <div id="share-buttons>                                                                                                                 <div id="facebook share-buttons"></div>
                                                                                  <div id="twitter share-buttons"></div>
                                                                          <div id="pinterest share-buttons"></div>
                                                                         <div id="google_plus share-buttons"></div>
                                                       </div>
             </figcaption>
                        </figure>

                    </li>
```

Comment: hey, can you draw the image to explain what you expect it to look like?

Comment: I can do, be five minutes. Thank you :)

Comment: also you can post your component.css into the CSS panel in jsfiddle, or paste it  into https://gist.github.com/ and make sure to mention and explain it in your question.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and sort out your indentation. Also you have extra tags that are not being used. There is a div tag below the empty h3 that is never closed.

Comment: I will do. Sorry I have extra tags because I forgot to remove them from the code. I have a bigger project for myself but this is what I'm having trouble with. I'll try paste it all into gist.github.com

Comment: In your HTML you are using "id" when you want to be using "class": id="twitter share-buttons". This, I think, is part of the problem as the CSS is styling those divs based on class.

Comment: @Dottsie you mentioned that you are just beginning to learn HTML and CSS, my suggestion is - don't go too far with HTML5 and CSS3, just learn the HTML4 and CSS2, until you're quite familiar with basics. e.g. the new `<header>` `<figure>` `<figcaption>` are all new HTML5 elements, you're not necessarily to use them to be honest. That will just make you learning process much harder. I'd say get started with http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html first.

Comment: @sdcr Thanks for that. Well I did some CSS years ago but kind of still have a slight grasp on it and I suppose I'm jumping a bit too far ahead of myself. Css3 and HTML5 are what's new to me so I thought I'd start with them but should really relearn the basics again. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you have used id's for your buttons. ID attributes are normally unique, it looks as though you meant class instead though owing to your CSS calling them by . instead of #

```
<div id="facebook">

// This is accessed in css by #facebook{float:left} 

<div class="facebook"> 

// This is accessed in css by .facebook{float:left}
```

If you are ever going to have more than one of an item on a page it is a class of item. Remember ID is unique.

Following that you can use float to get your objects to try and position themselves as far to one side as possible:

```
_________________________________________________
| A  | B  | C  | D  |                           |
|____|____|____|____|                           |
|_______________________________________________|
```

Here A B C and D are all floated left `float:left`, and push up as tight as the can.

```
_________________________________________________
|                           | Z  | Y  | X  | W  |
|                           |____|____|____|____|
|_______________________________________________|
```

Here W X Y and Z are all floated right `float:right`, and push up as tight as the can.

If you want them stacked vertically we can use clear. Clear stops there from being any floated items that are on the side that is stated, the upshot of that is that it will push things down below if its not allowed to have something on that side:

```
_________________________________________________
| A  |                                          |
|____|    |                                     |
| B  |  <-'                                     |
|____|    |                                     |
| c  |  <-'                                     |
|____|    |                                     |
| D  |  <-'                                     |
|____|                                          |
|                                               |
|_______________________________________________|
```

So in this case using `clear:left` on B forces it onto a new line below, clearing C forces D down etc. We don't want anything unexpected happening with wrapping so it is worth clearing both sides just for completeness so using `clear:both` will ensure that no two floated buttons are on the same line.

When your code has been condensed, it would look like this.

```
<header>
    <h1>Caption Hover Effects</h1>
</header>

<ul class="grid cs-style-2">

    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://domain/imagefile.jpc"/>
            <figcaption>                                      
              <div>
                  <div class="facebook share-buttons"></div>
                  <div class="twitter share-buttons"></div>
                  <div class="pinterest share-buttons"></div>
                  <div class="google_plus share-buttons"></div>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>                                
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this CSS for all share-buttons

```
.share-buttons{ 
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    height:32px;
    padding:2px;
    width:32px;
}
```

and the individual buttons as such

```
.share-buttons.facebook {
    background: url('images/facebook.png') no-repeat;
}
.share-buttons.twitter {
    background: url('images/twitter.png') no-repeat;
}
.share-buttons.pinterest {
    background: url('images/pinterest.png') no-repeat;
}
.share-buttons.google_plus {
    background: url('images/google_plus.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That makes so much sense now, thank you very much! I'll make this the answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, ids need to be unique, so I would change "share-buttons" to a class instead. Next, I see that you have three divs for social media icons, each with "share-buttons", but they are also wrapped in a wrapper with the same "share-buttons". I would remove that wrapper since you already have a wrapper div around all of that. Finally, give the newly created class "share-buttons" a "float: left;" and your images should align themselves like you're looking for. Also, make sure you clear your float "clear:both;" after this div.

Comment: Apparently I can't upload images here as I don't have enough reputation yet. here is the github: https://github.com/dottsie/div-positioning   I can explain how I want it to be. So it's an image that has two captions. One slides down from the top and the other up from the bottom. I have the sliding working. In the top caption I have a 5 star rating div I want on the left and the vote data for it underneath the stars and share button I need to the right of the stars.

Comment: I changed them like you said. I think... However I'm not sure what you mean by clear:both; or where to put that. Here's what I've changed in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/6uhw8c1p/1/

Comment: Dottsie, looks like Glen Hollard answered it better than I could. Looks like you should be covered :)